# How to add multiple values in a cookie index at once in php

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I have to create a cookie for a project (it's a simple e-shop website) that saves the items a registered user add to his shopping cart. The problem is that I can't make the cookie save multiple values at once (i.e. the user add more than 2 items to his cart). 
I succeeded to insert the items in my database with the id of the user, but if I print_r on the cookie only the user_id is stored in the cookie, not the items..
I precise that I'm still a newbie at php and this is an homework, so the code might not be safe or efficient but there are many functions that I haven't learnt yet at school.
Here's my code (I choose checkbox input to add in the cart) :
**index.php**

```
<?php require('inc_connexion.php'); ?>
<?php session_start() ; ?>
<?php require('inc_panier.php') ; ?> // Cookie page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Accueil</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <?php require('inc_header.php'); ?>
  <main>
    <h2 class="border-bot text-align-left">À la une</h2>
    <?php
    $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM products');
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
      $products[] = $row;
    }
    ?>

    <form action="" method="POST">
      <div class="catalogue">
        <?php foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
          <div class="product">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/90/000000/product.png" />
            <span><?php echo $product['product_nom'] ?></span>
            <span><?php echo $product['product_text'] ?></span>
            <span><?php echo $product['product_price'] ?>€</span>
            <span>Ajouter au panier
              <input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
            </span>
          </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
      </div>
      <?php
      if (isset($_SESSION['user_login'])) {
        $valider = '<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Valider le panier">';
      } else {
        $valider = '<a class="login" href="login.php">Connectez-vous pour valider</a>';
      }
      echo $valider;
      ?>
    </form>

      <?php
      if (isset($_POST['submit']) and (empty($_POST['product_id']))) {
        $message = '<p class="error">Vous n\'avez sélectionné aucun produit !</p>';
      }
      if (isset($message)) echo $message;
      ?>
    
  </main>
  <?php require('inc_footer_bar.php'); ?>
<?php require('inc_footer.php') ; ?>
```

And this is my cookie **inc_panier** :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']) and (!empty($_POST['product_id']))) {
  $articles = $_POST['product_id'];
  $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT user_id, user_login FROM users WHERE user_login = "' . $_SESSION['user_login'] . '"');
  $row = $result->fetch_array();
  $user_id = $row['user_id'];

  if (isset($_COOKIE['basket'])) {
    $cookie_value = $_COOKIE['basket'];
    $cookie_value = unserialize($cookie_value);
    $basket_data = serialize($cookie_value);

    foreach ($articles as $product_id) {
      $cookie_value['product_id'] = $product_id;
      $cookie_value['user_id'] = $user_id;
      $mysqli->query('INSERT INTO basket (user_id, product_id) VALUES (' . $user_id . ', ' . $product_id . ')');
  }
    }
 
  else {
    foreach ($articles as $product_id) {
      $user_basket['product_id'] = $product_id;
      $user_basket['user_id'] = $user_id;
      $mysqli->query('INSERT INTO basket (user_id, product_id) VALUES (' . $user_id . ', ' . $product_id . ')');
    }
   
    $basket_data = serialize($user_basket);

  }
 
  setcookie('basket', $basket_data, time() + 1296000);
}
?>
```

So I can store value in $user_basket['user_id'] and $cookie_value['user_id'] but not in $user_basket['product_id'] and $cookie_value['product_id'] because with  print_r(unserialize($_COOKIE['basket']) only user_id is displayed. 
So I guess it doesn't work with foreach, although all the items added by the user appear in my database..
Help please !

Comment: Why do you want to store this data into a cookie to begin with - when you are already using sessions?

Comment: `$basket_data = serialize($cookie_value);` - maybe you should do this _after_ you updated the cookie data, and not before?

Comment: @CBroe That's an homework following the chapter on the sessions and cookies so I assumed it was required but now that you mention it I realize it's not mentioned anywhere ^^', but just by curiosity I'd like to know the answer.
I'll try !